# why is the mapping on my texture not square?

Tags: modeling, texturing

I have watched a video on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbcQBgHh5NE) on how to create a can with texture.

The problem occurs when I will add the texture I have found.

the first problem can be seen in the first picture where I get a textured mesh which is not all square as it is in the video? why does mine have edges on the top?

the second problem can be seen on picture two where you can see that the texture on the can is almost all black/dark? it does not look like how the texture is supposed to look like.

I hope someone can help me with my problem.[image]
enter image description here

Comment: Please edit your question and add more information. Did you use unwrap from view? What is the texture supposed to look like? Please do not ask more than one question per post.

Comment: I used cylinder projection and the texture should be all square as in the video linked. The texture is the one you see on the picture. As told in my previous titel I am new at blender so I have not that many terms for what i am doing.

Comment: It looks like you did project from view not cylinder projection.